# Package.json exports with webpack 5 - dynamically imported module not found

Tags: node.js, json, webpack, webpack-5

I am having a bit of trouble reconciling the path of a dynamic import for i18n locales. Here's the relevant code -

```js
function getLoader(
  lang: SupportedLanguage,
  ns: SupportedNamespace
): NamespaceLoader | undefined {
  const matrixToCheck = UNSUPPORTED_MATRIX[ns];
  const isSupported = matrixToCheck && matrixToCheck.indexOf(lang) === -1;
  if (isSupported) {
    const path = `./locales/${lang}/${ns}.json`;
    const name = `${lang}_${ns}`;
    const named = {
      [name]: () => import(`${path}`),
    };
    return named[name];
  }
}
...
// eventual output
const SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES = {en: {namespace1: () => import('./locales/en/namespace1.json')}
```

My goal is manage all of the relevant translations in a single npm package, handle all of the dynamic import set-up at build time, and then consumers can invoke the getter (`getTranslation` in this case) in their respectives apps for the language and namespace of their choice to get the payload at runtime.

[Based on this GH thread](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/14970#issuecomment-571887546), I wanted to reconcile the locale `dist` path via the `package.json`

```js
 ...
 "exports": {
    ".": "./dist/src/main.js",
    "./": "./dist/"
  },
 ...
```

e.g. when I publish the package, based on that `exports` config, the consumer would know know how to reconcile the path, either relative or package-name-prefix when the getter is invoked

```js
const fn = () => import('./locales/fr/myNamespace.json')  /// doesn't work
const anotherFn = () => import('@examplePackageName/locales/fr/myNamespace.json') /// doesn't work
```

Since everything is dynamic, I am using the [CopyWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/) to include the locales in the `dist` folder.

This works as expected locally, but when I create the `dist`, I get the error `Error: Module not found ./relative/path/to/the/json/I/want.json`.

My question:

What am I missing? Is there a simple way to expose these translations so that other apps can include them in their bundles via an npm-installed package?

Here's my Webpack config, happy to provide other info as needed

```js
const path = require("path");
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

const getPlugins = () => {
  return [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [{ from: "locales", to: "locales" }],
    }),
  ];
};

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: {
    main: "./src/main.ts",
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "src/[name].js",
    chunkFilename: "chunk.[name].js",
    libraryTarget: "commonjs2",
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: [".json", ".ts", ".js"],
    alias: {
      "@locales": path.resolve(__dirname, "locales/*"),
    },
  },
  plugins: getPlugins(),
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: [/\.test\.ts$/],
        include: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
        loader: "ts-loader",
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exports directive prescribes to define all files allowed for import explicitly ([documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/packages.html#packages_subpath_exports)). It allows developer to hide internal package file structure. What's not exported by this directive is only available to import inside the package and not outside of it. It's made to simplify maintenance. It allows developers to rename files or change file structure without fear of breaking dependent packages and applications.

So if you want to make internal files visible for import, you should export them with exports directive explicitly, like this:

```js
{
  "exports": {
      ".": "./dist/esm/src/main.js",
      "./dist/shared/locale/fr_fr.json": "./dist/shared/locale/fr_fr.json"
  }
}
```

I'm not sure wether Webpack handling this case, because it's an experimental feature yet. But this is how Node.js works now.

#### Why it is so

Changing your app file structure is a major change in semver terms, so you need to bump a version everytime you rename or delete files. To avoid it you can specify which files are part of public interface of the package.

Comment: The linked issue explicitly said `...if exports specifies a file, it hides other files. If exports specifies a directory, then all files in it can be accessed deeply (unlike pre Node 13.2).`  which is I think my main point of confusion. Perhaps it is implementation error, perhaps this statement is not true. Thanks for the info.

Comment: You should link https://webpack.js.org/guides/package-exports/, not the node.js documentation